# modulus operation division property

Tags: math, division, modulus

i have an equation ,

```
((a*b*c*d)/(e*f*g*h))%m
```

My question is , Can i first apply multiplication property

```
(a*b) mod(n) = (a*mod(n)) * (b*mod(n) ) mod(n)
```

to numerator and then denominator , so that numerator and denominator becomes a single value , and then solve the division operation?

```
(a/b) mod(n) = (a*inv(b)) mod(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `N = a*b*c*d` and `D = e*f*g*h`. We want to calculate:

```
(N/D) mod n = (N * inv(D)) mod n
```

We can use the multiplication property here in the following way:

```
(N * inv(D)) mod n = ((N mod n) * (inv(D) mod n)) mod n
```

To calculate `N mod n` we can apply the multiplication property again so the first part of answer is yes - you can apply the multiplication property to the numerator before solving the division because you will have to do it anyway.

The result of `(inv(D) mod n)` is a number `X` that satisfies the equation:

```
(D * X) mod n = 1
((D mod n) * (X mod n)) mod n = 1
```

If you apply the multiplication property to the denominator before solving the division you will get:

```
(((D mod n) mod n) * (X mod n)) mod n = 1
```

However `(D mod n) mod n = D mod n` so it doesn't matter. It means that the second part of the answer is also yes - you can apply the multiplication property to the denominator before solving the division.