# While calculating f(N) = 0^0+1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+...+N^N,in java?It works fine for small values of N,but for big values of N it takes a long time

Tags: java

How to calculate **f(N)mod M** in shortest possible time ,
where **1<=N<=10^9 ,1<=M<=10^3** ..
I tried to first calculate **f(N)** then to **mod** .im able to calculate **f(N)modM** but it is taking a long time for computation when N is large(ex. **N=10^9**) I need to calculate the result in shortest possible time..Please help im new to stackoverflow.
Thanks for the help in advance.
Heres my code

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SuhanaEquation {

static void f(int N,int M){
    int num,res;
    long mod=0L;
    int ires=0;

    for (int l = 0; l <= N; l++){
        mod+=(l*(l%M))% M;
    }
    System.out.println(mod%M);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=scn.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int aa=scn.nextInt();
        int bb=scn.nextInt();
        System.out.println(aa+"  "+bb);
        SuhanaEquation.f(aa, bb);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide some of the coding you´ve done already and exaclly describe you problem rather than just saying `But im unable to calculate f(N)`.

Comment: paste your code.

Comment: (a+b) mod M = a mod M + b mod M. hope it helps ;)

Comment: This is an algorithmic exercise. It is intended that you cannot calculate f(N) and you must find another solution. Look at dehasi's comment.

Comment: @FatTony .. Sorry Im new to stackoverflow . I have added the code i have done.Thanx for your help :)

Comment: @dehasi . I have already tried your solution.It works for smaller values of N But Im unable to  calculate N^N for large value of N i.e(N=10^9)

Comment: @RajThakur you should look at another `mod` properties. like `N*N mod M = (N mod M) * (N mod M)`

Comment: @dehasi .. I get it .. Ill try and let you know .

Comment: Thank you guys for this immediate  help .Being new to stackoverflow i never thought it would be such good place .Thanks to all of you for your efforts .

Comment: @dehasi I think that your second property is wrong. Example : `5*5 mod 3`. `5*5 mod 3` cannot be 4. I think that it is something life `N*N mod M = (N * (N mod M)) mod M`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle you are right. [here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826787/modulus-operation-division-property) discussion about modulo properties.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle . Tried with your formula .The results seems to  be good,but it is taking a long time for computation.Any way we can speed up the things.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated,I have updated the question and code as well

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this process without using `BigInteger`.

Two notes:

> (a + b + c) % m

is equivalent to

> (a % m + b % m + c % m) % m

and

> (a * b * c) % m

is equivalent to

> ((a % m) * (b % m) * (c % m)) % m

As a result, you can calculate each term using a recursive function in O(log p):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    static long f(int n, int p, int m) {
       if (p == 0) return 1;
       int nm = n % m;
       long  r = f(nm, p / 2, m);
       r = (r * r) % m;
       if (p % 2 == 0) return r;
       return (r * nm) % m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = scn.nextLong();
        long m = scn.nextLong();
        long r = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            r = (r + f(i, i, (int) m)) % m;

        System.out.println(r);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer .But this code works well for small values of N. When I input ***N=10^9*** it takes forever for computation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be much faster but, as Md. Rezwanul Haque and dehasi noticed,

> (a+b) mod M = a mod M + b mod M

so maybe this will works:

```
static void f(int N,int M){

    int num,res;
    long mod=0L;
    int ires=0;

    for (int l = 0; l <= N; l++){
        int aux = l%M;

        mod+=(aux*aux)%M;

    }
    System.out.println(mod%M);

}
```

Doing this you are multiplying shorter number so it should be faster.

Good luck!